# Php Dom Document results error

Tags: php, domdocument

I would like to scrape some elements from html, but I am unable to scrape the data as I need.

html

```
<div class="opinions">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="imgcontainers">
<a href="domainname.com" title="title">                                                 `<img width="160" src="image.jpg" />`
</a>
</div>
<p class="caption">
<a href="domainname.com" class="head">asdfad</a>
<span>November 03, 2015 09:29 This is article title</span>
</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$classname = 'opinions';
$html = get_page($url);
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$articles = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

$p = $articles->getElementsByTagName('a');
$div = $articles->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($p as $value){
    $title = $value->getAttribute("href");
    echo $title;
}
```

when I run this script I am getting this error "Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()"

What I exactly need is,  I need every href link and img src path (if there) and span text value of this . Please suggest your advice how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can learn something from my [code](https://github.com/jflee0315/extractHtml)

Or, if you decide to include my function, here is how I do it:

```
    $html = ""; //your html
    $props = array(
    array("tagname"=>"div", "props"=>array("class"=>"opinions")),
    //the '/' before 'a' is for all descendant <a> of <div>
    array("tagname"=>"/a"),
    );
    $options = array("property"=>"href");
    require_once 'getNodeValue.php';
    $hrefs = getNodeValue($html, $props, $options);
    print_r($hrefs);
```